# Installation of Ubuntu 14.04.1 faild on Dell Inspiron N5040

Tags: system-installation

I tried to install Ubuntu 14.04.1 64-bit version from USB and when installation starts it says that I do not have at least 6.5 GB of free drive space. I have 64-bit based processor with 4 GB of RAM and I currently have 185 GB free HDD space. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The partition in which you are trying to install may not have the required space. Please make a new partition with atleast 6.5 GB.

Comment: But I didn't make it to that part. On the installation start when it checks system requirements like internet connection, free drive space, etc it says to me that I do not have at least 6.5 GB of free drive space.